# Laravel 4.2 Form SUbmit Friendly URL

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4, friendly-url

I have a form in Laravel 4.2

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'search', 'method'=>'get', 'class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left' ,'role'=>'search'))}}
<div class="form-group ">
   <input list="browsers" name="topic" class="form-control " placeholder="Search">
     <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
     </datalist>
</div>
<button class="gray-button"><span>Search</span></button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

When I Click on submit button, I get URL like

```
http://localhost/car/public/search?topic=dfg
```

But I want to have a URL like

```
http://localhost/car/public/search/dfg
```

Do I need to change some code in Form?

Or in Router.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: You probably have to use javascript

Comment: Why?
I can have a search URL in Codeigniter like localhost/search/topic_name

So, I can have it here.

There must be a way

Comment: The problem isn't the routing. It is the form. You can't use dynamic form data (like topic) to generate an URL without javascript. Alternatively you could make a server redirect from `search?topic=dfg` to `search/dfg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need JavaScript if you don't want to do a server redirect as @lukasgeiter pointed in the comments. You also need to setup a route for that particular search URL. The route should look something like this using a route closure:

```
Route::get('search/{topic}', function ($topic)
{
    // code goes here
});
```

For the client side you need to stop the form from submitting and go to a manually built URL when submitting the form. So you could have something like this:

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'search', 'method'=>'get', 'id' => 'searchForm', 'class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left' ,'role'=>'search'))}}
    <div class="form-group ">
       <input list="browsers" name="topic" class="form-control " placeholder="Search">
         <datalist id="browsers">
            <option value="Internet Explorer">
            <option value="Firefox">
            <option value="Chrome">
            <option value="Opera">
            <option value="Safari">
         </datalist>
    </div>
    <button class="gray-button"><span>Search</span></button>
{{Form::close()}}

<script>
    document.getElementById('searchForm').onsubmit = function (event)
    {
        // Prevent the form from submitting
        event.preventDefault();

        // Build the url using the form action and the topic value
        var topic = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="topic"]')[0];
        window.location.href = this.action + '/' + encodeURIComponent(topic.value);
    };
</script>
```